# Raspberry Pi: MJPEG encoding

Tags: encoding, raspberry-pi, transcoding, raspbian, openmax

I'd like to transcode video from H264 to MJPEG on the Pi.

Schematically, there's a process that injects an H264 raw stream in a pipe and takes out (in real time) the same stream, encoded with MJPEG, from anoher pipe. Currently, the black box that takes in H264 and spits out MJPEG is a simple transcoding program, made with FFMPEG. This approach works well in modern workstations, but it is too CPU-taxing on the Raspberry Pi.

I know that The Pi supports hardware H264 decoding with OpenMax, and doesn't support MJPEG encoding out of the box.

Is there a way (complicated at will) to do MJPEG hardware encoding as well?

Are there examples on how to do this kind of transcoding with openMax?

(I'm aware of the existence of [this project](https://github.com/dickontoo/omxtx), but it doesn't satisfy question 1)

Comment: 9 years later.. still no answer on this topic. Its a shame